# how to Apply changes automatically to xhtml (jsf) pages on save action with intelliJ and jboss

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, jboss

I'm triying to use intelliJ idea because the support of netbeans to jboss its so bad, i have to redeploy the complete project after save a simple xhtml page to view the result, i want to save any file (xhtml, classes, resources) and apply the changes immediately only with CTRL + S command in the intelliJ IDE, someone that knows the correct way to do this ?

i dont know how the war exploded works, can someone explain me, i tried with some tutorials but i press CTRL + S and not works.

Comment: I Use Jboss and netbeans and I agree it is so tedious to make a simple change and see it reflected. I wrote this about how to make it a little faster. You still have to rebuild the project but with way less work, take a look. http://serverfault.com/questions/804979/how-to-auto-deploy-with-jboss

Comment: with glassfish server its so easy, you can view the changes immediately i was thinking that could be the ide

Comment: Yeah I came from glassfish also it was nice and easy. I think it has more to do with the server than the IDE

Comment: My Eclipse (Mars) and JBoss (from 6 up to 10)  all have this functionality, so it might be more in the 'server plugin' in the IDE than in the application server.

Comment: Nice, i will try with eclipse thks

Comment: This is still not working in IJ 2021.3.3. The file name tab doesn't even indicate changes to the file, e.g. showing an asterisk (*), because the file seems to be save automatically? Not sure here. However, pressing Ctrl+S doesn't do **anything** to the IDE state, not to say there's nothing being performed to hotdeploy to the server. This really makes IntelliJ + JSF + JBoss an absolute no-go AFA for me.